# php string and text file comparison

Tags: php, string, text-files

I'm writing a php code to find if a given string has anagrams using a dictionary text file. The program has to shuffle the given string into possible 4 letter words in an array and check if the words in the array are meaningful horizontally and vertically when checked with the dictionary text. This is my code to shuffle a given string and compare it with words in text file and return result if it matches. But it does not display any result. Where am i making a mistake?

```
$str = 'NORTH EAST'; 
$shuffled = str_shuffle($str);
$dictionary = "Dict.txt";
//function to compare shuffled string and data in file
function getLineWithString($dictionary, $shuffled) {
    $lines = file($dictionary);
        foreach ($lines as $lineNumber => $line) {
        if (strpos($line, $shuffled) !== false) { //if shuffled string matches with words in txt file
            return $line; //return string if matched
        }
    }$str = 'NORTH EAST'; 
$shuffled = str_shuffle($str);
$dictionary = "Dict.txt";
//function to compare shuffled string and data in file
function getLineWithString($dictionary, $shuffled) {
    $lines = file($dictionary);
        foreach ($lines as $lineNumber => $line) {
        if (strpos($line, $shuffled) !== false) { //if shuffled string matches with words in txt file
            return $line; //return string if matched
        }
    }
    return -1;
    echo"found $line";
}


    return -1;
    echo"found $line";
}
```